# How to join an n-dimension array with different separators for each level?

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

## Sample input

### Array

Here I am showing a 3-dimension array but the actual number of dimensions vary and is known as `n`.

```js
[
  [
    [1,2],
    [3,4]
  ],
  [
    [5,6],
    [7,8]
  ]
]
```

### Separators

It has the same length (`n`) as the number of dimensions of the array where the i-th element represent the separator of the i-th level of the array.

```js
[',', '_', '-']
```

---

## Desired output

```js
1-2_3-4,5-6_7-8
```

---

## What I've tried

It works for a 3-dimension array but not for a 4-dimension one.

**I know what is going wrong with my code but I have no idea how to fix it.**

**Besides, I think there are simpler and/or more efficient methods.**

### 3-dimension (working)

```js
const array = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]];
const separators = [',', '_', '-'];
const _separators = separators.reverse();
let i;
function join(array, first = false) {
  const next = Array.isArray(array[0]);
  let result;
  if (next) {
     result = array.map(e => {
       if (first) { i = 0; }
       return join(e);
     });
     i++;
     result = result.join(_separators[i]);
  }
  else {
    result = array.join(_separators[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
const result = join(array, true);
console.log(result);
```

### 4-dimension (not working properly)

```js
const array = [[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]],[[['A','B'],['C','D']],[['E','F'],['G','H']]]];
const separators = ['|', ',', '_', '-'];
const _separators = separators.reverse();
let i;
function join(array, first = false) {
  const next = Array.isArray(array[0]);
  let result;
  if (next) {
     result = array.map(e => {
       if (first) { i = 0; }
       return join(e);
     });
     i++;
     result = result.join(_separators[i]);
  }
  else {
    result = array.join(_separators[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
const result = join(array, true);
console.log(result);
// desired output: 1-2_3-4,5-6_7-8|A-B_C-D,E-F_G-H
```

Comment: something like `const magiJoin = (arr, [first, ...rest]) => arr.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? magiJoin(e, rest) : e).join(first);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this with recursion

```js
const join = (array, separators, depth) => {
  if (depth < separators.length -1) {
    return array.map(el => join(el, separators, depth + 1)).join(separators[depth]);
  } else {
    return array.join(separators[depth]);
  }
};

{
  const array = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]];
  const separators = [',', '_', '-'];
  console.log(join(array, separators, 0));
}
{
  const array = [[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]],[[['A','B'],['C','D']],[['E','F'],['G','H']]]];
  const separators = ['|', ',', '_', '-'];
  console.log(join(array, separators, 0));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Why I have forgot just to pass the depth as an argument!